# Efficiently find index of DataFrame values in array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` that resembles:

```
x     y     z
--------------
0     A     10
0     D     13
1     X     20
...
```

and I have two sorted arrays for every possible value for `x` and `y`:

```
x_values = [0, 1, ...]
y_values = ['a', ..., 'A', ..., 'D', ..., 'X', ...]
```

so I wrote a function:

```
def lookup(record, lookup_list, lookup_attr):
    return np.searchsorted(lookup_list, getattr(record, lookup_attr))
```

and then call:

```
df_x_indicies = df.apply(lambda r: lookup(r, x_values, 'x')
df_y_indicies = df.apply(lambda r: lookup(r, y_values, 'y')

# df_x_indicies: [0, 0, 1, ...]
# df_y_indicies: [26, ...]
```

but is there are more performant way to do this? and possibly multiple columns at once to get a returned `DataFrame` rather than a series?

I tried:

```
np.where(np.in1d(x_values, df.x))[0]
```

but this removes duplicate values and that is not desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your index arrays to `pd.Index` objects to make lookup fast(er).

```
u, v = map(pd.Index, [x_values, y_values])
pd.DataFrame({'x': u.get_indexer(df.x), 'y': v.get_indexer(df.y)})

   x  y
0  0  1
1  0  2
2  1  3
```

Where,

```
x_values
# [0, 1]

y_values
# ['a', 'A', 'D', 'X']
```

---

As to your requirement of having this work for multiple columns, you will have to iterate over each one. Here's a version of the code above that should generalise to N columns and indices.

```
val_list = [x_values, y_values] # [x_values, y_values, z_values, ...]
idx_list = map(pd.Index, val_list)
pd.DataFrame({
    f'{c}': idx.get_indexer(df[c]) for idx, c in zip(idx_list, df)})

   x  y
0  0  1
1  0  2
2  1  3
```

Comment: That is clever! and also something I have not seen in the previous S.O. posts I read

Comment: @SumNeuron If it helps, please consider accepting the answer. Thanks.

Comment: will do, but I have been advised in the past not to immediately accept answers, but to give some time for others in the community to chime in other ideas as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Update using `Series` with `.loc` , you may can also try with `reindex`

```
pd.Series(range(len(x_values)),index=x_values).loc[df.x].tolist()
Out[33]: [0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: I think I might not have be clear about which indices I am trying to retrieve. I would like the indices for columns `x` and `y` based on the position their values occur at in `x_values`, and `y_values` so I would expect that the returned indicies for `x` (based off this trivial example) to be `[0, 0, 1, ...]`